When to use a simple formula vs an iterative solution?
I have this well known formula for calculating the investment sum f(x) = s*(1+i)^x
s = starting sum
i = interest
X (variable) = number of periods.
What does this function look like if I add an amount m at the end of each period? Isn't this a recursive function that cannot be written other than through iterations?
If the answer is "yes, the solution can be achieved only by using some iterative approach"
Could you please give me a general rule of thumb in which cases the usage of iterations is obligatory which means that I can not use some "static formula"
Thank you very much

What language is ензшсфд and what does it mean? It looks like something like enzshsfd transliterated into Latin letters, which is a lot of consonants.

$m(1+i)^x+m(1+1)^{x-1}+m(1+1)^{x-2}+\cdots+m(1+i)+m$ is a geometric series and easily simplified.

@Henry
Thanks for the answer,  but if I get you right I guess the fact you have this "+...+" type of a notation pinpoints that the solution is iterative - this is not just a hard static function.

If you consider  $m\times (1+i)\times(1+i) \times\cdots \times(1+i)= m(1+i)^x$ and describe the left-hand side as "iterative" and the right-hand side as "static" then there is also a "static" form of the geometric series expression in my earlier comment.

@Henry
nice point let me correct myself:
What I call a "static function" is a function where to get some output result I do not need to append my own function's midway results.  I meant more like a "one-stop shop" - take those inputs:  initial sum, interest, addition one per period sum, and the amount of periods do some magic and and give me the output sum.
If I understand right In such a case we can NOT get such a static function, can we?
Thank you very much!

Yes you can here - just simply the geometric series.
